# GIF of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{i^{2/3}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

I am asked to find the GIF (greatest integer function) of the sum:$$\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{i^{2/3}}$$

I am able to find the lower limit of the sum by using the fact that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac{1}{i^{2/3}}$$ is greater than 
$$\int_{1}^{1000}x^{-2/3}dx$$ 
But I am unable to find the upper limit which will help me find the GIF. Any help is appreaciated.

Edit : I realized I should add this, the answer is 27. So I basically have to prove that the given sum lies between 27 and 28, of which I have proved 27 is the lower limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strict lower limit is
$$\int_1^{1001}x^{-2/3}dx = 3(\sqrt[3]{1001} - 1) > 3(\sqrt[3]{1000} - 1) = 27.$$
A strict upper limit is
$$1 + \int_1^{1000}x^{-2/3}dx = 1 + 3(\sqrt[3]{1000} - 1) = 28.$$

So, the answer is $\boxed{27}$.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, it's about halfway between these bounds, [27.557](https://repl.it/repls/PreemptiveHandmadeArguments).

Comment: How do you prove that 1 + $\int_{1}^{1000}x^{-2/3}dx$ is greater than the given sum in my question. I haven't solved similar questions before so it's difficult to understand.

Comment: We take out the first term in the series, $1$, and then approximate $\int_1^{1000} x^{-2/3}dx$ with a right Riemann sum -- $2^{-2/3} + 3^{-2/3} + \cdots + 1000^{-2/3}$ -- which will be less than the actual integral because $x^{-2/3}$ is decreasing.

Comment: Had to learn about Riemann sums and now I can understand finally. Thanks for help.